# Hi, trying to obtain the mean from the array values using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

Im new to bash programming. Here im trying to obtain the mean from the array values.

Heres what im trying:

```
${GfieldList[@]} | awk '{ sum += $1; n++ } END { if (n > 0) print "mean: " sum / n; }';
```

Using $1 Im not able to get all the values? Guys pls help me out in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each non-empty line of input, this will sum everything on the line and print the mean:

```
$ echo 21 20 22 | awk 'NF {sum=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)sum+=$i; print "mean=" sum / NF; }'
mean=21
```

#### How it works

- `NF`

  This serves as a condition: the statements which follow will only be executed if the number of fields on this line, `NF`, evaluates to true, meaning non-zero.
- `sum=0`

  This initializes `sum` to zero.  This is only needed if there is more than one line.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)sum+=$i`

  This sums all the fields on this line.
- `print "mean=" sum / NF`

  This prints the sum of the fields divided by the number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

The bare

```
${GfieldList[@]}
```

will not print the array to the screen. You want this:

```
printf "%s\n" "${GfieldList[@]}"
```

All those quotes are definitely needed  .